# Outlook WebAddin is detected as contextual addin instead of ribbon addin

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

We have created Outlook Ribbon Webaddin. It is working as expected(ribbon Addin) and loading in top ribbon place. But for some customer, it is loading as contextual Addin.

**Manifest URL** : https://www.backflipt.com/app/addin/Backflipt-Beta.xml

**Outlook diagnostics info :**

> {"host"     : "Outlook", "platform": "PC", "version":
>   "15.0.0000.0000"}

Is there any way outlook configuration affects manifest loading way?

Check the below image(blurred for security reasons) : 
Green color section is the plugin which is loaded as contextual addin
[image]

> Seems it is not an issue with outlook mail box version or client
>   version. I can see Cisco webex is installed in his ribbon. If it is
>   because of version, then he should not able to install any in ribbon
>   right.

Comment: You can use minimum requirement set like 1.3,1.4 ,1.5 in your manifest to restrict loading of your add-in in older versions

Comment: how to check mail box version with outlook client version mapping? for that same person it is working fine in browser.

Comment: @mufeezahmed check my comment

Comment: Please check following documentation for requirement set in manifests https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/tutorial-api-requirement-sets.   There  are diagnostics APIs which will give you outlook client versions  ,where as browsers always runs on latest version of outlook ,desktop clients needs to be updated to suitable version .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the version of Outlook that you posted in your question (15.0.0000.0000), the reason it's showing up in the horizontal bar, is because that Outlook client is significantly out of date. Please update Outlook to 15.0.4805.1000 or higher.

Please also make sure you have the following updates downloaded and installed as well (they are all required):
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3114816/march-8-2016-update-for-office-2013-kb3114816
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3114828/march-8-2016-update-for-office-2013-kb3114828
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51285

Answer (score 1):

This happens generally for customers who are using older version of outlook ,most of the time upgrading outlook to latest/newer  version will solve the issue