# How to Change the addin from contextual to Ribbon menu Addin in my Mac outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-store, outlook-for-mac

[Screenshot of the Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLJlR.png)

In my Mac Outlook, i see the app store button inside the email, instead of Ribbon Bar.
& when i install a addin, it also shows up inside of an email, instead of Ribbon Bar.

i have another addin that is installed in the Ribbon Menu. 
is there a setting i should do, to shift this addin to ribbon & make it load vertically.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot showing your scenario? If store is not available in ribbon, check if your Outlook is up-to-date.

Comment: To answer your question there isn't any user settings to move add-ins to ribbon. The add-in developer decides where the add-in has to be shown.

Comment: Can you check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50989849/outlook-webaddin-is-detected-as-contextual-addin-instead-of-ribbon-addin  Seems like Cisco plugin is causing it in some cases.

Comment: Found out that Ribbon Menu Bar add-ins are only supported in below Outlook versions:

In Windows:
- if O365, Version 1603 (Build 6769.0000) or later
- if Outlook/Office 2016, Version 16.0.4678.1000 or later
- if Outlook/Office 2013, Version 15.0.5041.1001 or later

- Mac Outlook to 15.0.4805.1000 or higher

will update & see if it works.